# Removal of files in sudo (Terminal)

Tags: cache

Should I remove this file in my terminal for better performance?

In a simpler explanation should I run:

```
cd
ls
rm -r .cache
```

for better performance?

My assumption is that it will have to compile less.  Thank you!

Comment: what file are you referring to?

Comment: browser and third party attachments

Comment: Can you please provide the path to this file? For example: `~/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache` thanks!

Comment: In a simpler explanation should I cd -> ls -> rm -r .cache for better performance?

Comment: What makes you think you'll get better performance?  Usually caches are there to improve performance.  Are you having a problem with particular software?

Comment: I thought that the disk space it would free up would help my initial start up, but I just remembered these are two different memories.  Sorry, lack of sleep.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the command you are looking for and do not use sudo here:

```
rm -r ~/.cache/*/*
```

It may ask you if you want to remove a write-protected file, if so, type `n` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to proceed.

Alternatively, you could do this instead:

```
cd
ls -a
rm -r .cache/*/*
```

This may actually slow performance down as the cache is used to speed things up but it will free up some disk space.

Comment: @VariableSyntax No problem, I actually cleaned this directory out recently for disk space reasons and I noticed that performance suffers when opening directories in Nautilus because the thumbnails for all the files need to be regenerated.